# Decrease the line spacing in TinyMCE textarea

Tags: html, tinymce, richtextbox, newline

I am using TinyMCE to provide a rich text editing text editor. But the line spacing between the lines is too much. I have added a screenshot that shows the line spacing I get on pressing an enter. What can be done about it  [image: TinyMCE Screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a css class that is applied to the TinyMCE html content. It looks like you have `<p>` tags causing the spacing. Honestly, it looks pretty good to me. But you can override in the css class:

```
.tinymce-content p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 0;
}
```

See the [tinymce docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code that you have given me but there is another problem. Until an enter is hit the line goes on in the text editor. I mean a scroll bar appears and then it goes past the width. How can I contain the text with in the box. No body wants to see horizontal scroll bar

Comment: Please post this as a separate question.

Comment: Here I have posted this as a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464929/how-to-prevent-horizontal-scrolling-of-mce-editor

Comment: Actually, i was having same problem in **Aloha Editor**. But still it solves my problem by doing this:
`.aloha-textarea p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 0;
}`

Comment: does not work for me. I even tried changing 2px to a huge number, no change.

Comment: this is wrong answer, because message later is sent to user with double spacings..

Comment: @danludwig, do you need to mark those properties !important ? Without marking them as !important its not working

Answer (score 14):

You can add custom css to your CSS-editor like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        editor_css : "/content_css.css"
});
```

See docs here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:editor_css

You can then set a line-height property to whatever height you wish in that file.

You can also change a setting where you can switch between generating paragraph tags (p) or linebreak tags (br) with something like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '' // Needed for 3.x
});
```

See the docs here for more info: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:force_br_newlines

I think TinyMCE does paragraphs as standard when you hit enter, that is why you get a big margin between your lines. You can also use shift+enter like in Word to get a new line that is a line break instead of paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Good luck! Sometimes it's nice to use the main site css in an editor that is used for managing content to make it look more real. Sometimes that's only annoying :P

Comment: this option will overwrite css used for the tinymce UI like buttons, but not the content. content_css is the correct here to use

Comment: This works for me, the above "correct answer" does not work for me.

Comment: As of 3.5, use `forced_root_blocks : 'br'` instead. https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@force_br_newlines/

Comment: Actually, found I need `forced_root_blocks : ''`

Answer (score 9):

You can force TinyMCE to output divs instead of paragraphs.  Just put this line in your tinyMCE.init section:

```
forced_root_block : 'div',
```

Answer (score 6):

I know,
This post is old, but it may help someone.

'force_br_newlines'  and 'force_p_newlines' are deprecated as of 3.5.

Use [forced_root_blocks](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:force_br_newlines) instead:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '' // Needed for 3.x
});
```

Comment: This gives very different results, it's not just removing the padding but the entire paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

From tinyMCE 4.x you can specify this option

`forced_root_block_attrs: { "style": "margin: 5px 0;" }`

this will append `style: margin: 5px 0;` for every `p` tag.

P.S: it will not work for copy/paste content.

docs:

- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#forced_root_block
- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#example-using-forced_root_block_attrs

Comment: This is the best solution. FYI to get no extra special spacing, similar to writing, say, an email, use `forced_root_block_attrs: { "style": "margin: 0 0;" }`

Answer (score 2):

If you would like sometimes to have the extra space and sometimes not, then leave TinyMCE as is. And when you want the tighter space between paragraphs instead of pressing enter to go to the next line, press enter and shift together.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution I've encountered so far... so you may use it:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    style_formats : [
            {title : 'Line height 20px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '20px'}},
            {title : 'Line height 30px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '30px'}}
    ]
});
```

Anyway... that worked for me