# Plone - TinyMCE editor - line breaks with double instead single line spacing

Tags: tinymce, plone, zope

We are using Plone 4.1.3 and the default TinyMCE editor.   When we press the Enter key in TinyMCE, it produces a double line spacing instead of single line.   We found a few similar questions and answers on this issue in the forum but don't know and cannot find the TinyMCE configuration file to modify to make line break into single line spacing.  There is also nothing in Site Setup or ZMI to configure this for TinyMCE.

We found this the forum but it is not pertaining to plone.
[Decrease the line spacing in TinyMCE textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463621/decrease-the-line-spacing-in-tinymce-textarea)

Thank you very much in anticipation

cmgui

Answer (score 3):

CSS.  These are just paragraph elements (<p> tags). -- style them!

http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/TinyMCE-Plone-4-customizing-the-styles-for-own-CSS-classes-td5954678.html

Comment: Or use shift+enter to put a br tag inside the p tags.

Answer (score 1):

As sdupton pointed out, this is indeed on purpose; enter is supposed to be a paragraph break, and behaves the same way in applications like Word. You can insert line breaks by shift-enter, but it's not encouraged to do that on the web, since text flows differently depending on font size and window size (and OS!).

If you want paragraphs to have less spacing, use CSS to reduce the margin/padding.